# Update XML Document

Tags: xml, document

I want to update an XML Document with the node `<ConfiguredValue>` where `Path="\Package.Variables[User::LastRunDate].Properties[Value]" ValueType="DateTime">`

Can somebody please share some code to update XML document with desired node?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTSConfiguration>
  <DTSConfigurationHeading>
    <DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="contoso\johnR" GeneratedFromPackageName="UserPrefUtility" GeneratedFromPackageID="{E8B9B96A-7A1F-4DE9-9814-0B9F290CF021}" GeneratedDate="10/25/2010 4:15:43 PM"/>
  </DTSConfigurationHeading>
  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[HYDCRMTRN01.InsphereModelTest_Custom].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=contoso;Initial Catalog=contosodb;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=SSIS-UserPrefUtility-{0E1E1762-E9E4-453E-8D4A-3760E77292B3}contoso.contosodb;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>
  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Variables[User::CreateLogs].Properties[Value]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>true</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>
  **<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Variables[User::LastRunDate].Properties[Value]" ValueType="DateTime">
    <ConfiguredValue>1/15/2012 2:32:00 AM</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>**

  <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Variables[User::SdkUrl].Properties[Value]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>http://contoso/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx</ConfiguredValue>
  </Configuration>
</DTSConfiguration>
```

Comment: What language, technology, or environment are you using?  Also, what is `[User::LastRunDate]` supposed to be?  That's not valid XPath.

Comment: It looks like an sqlserver integration server package configuration file I think he is asking for someone to write him some code to update a field of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
emacs document.xml
```

( honestly, without more context to the question -- do you want to modify the
  document with xslt or using Java/DOM or whatever -- that's as good an answer
  as any. )